# how to transform an Array to an N-ary tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, transform, tree-structure

I have an Array that I need to transform it to an N-ary tree.
I know the value of N, and the total number of nodes.

I give you an example in the picture below. The N-ary tree should be ordered as illustrated.

[Link to image here](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=13994fa)

I can't figure it out. I need an algorithm to do that. The program I'm writing is in javascript but an answer in pseudocode is fine also.

Appreciate your help!

**[Edited]**

I found a solution using the algorithm from here: [Construct a complete K-ary tree from preorder traversal](http://pastebin.com/0gVATpRa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the algorithm from here:

[Construct a complete K-ary tree from preorder traversal](http://pastebin.com/0gVATpRa)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code/ C# version. Please ask any C# related questions in comments. The key thing here is use of a first-in-first-out data structure, the queue `parents` in the snippet below. The method `convertToN_aryTree` returns root node of the resulting n-ary tree.

```
public class Node
{
    public int data;
    public int nCount; // 'n' in n-ary
    public Node[] children; // this needs to be initialised to length n

    public Node(int d, int n)
    {
        data = d;
        nCount = n;
        children = new Node[n];
    }
}

// data is teh array and n is branch factor of the tree
Node convertToN_aryTree(int[] data, int n)
{
    if(data.Length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    Node root = new Node(data[0], n);
    Node currParent = root;
    Node curr;
    int currChildCount = 0;
    Queue<Node> parents = new Queue();
    for(int i = 1; i<data.Length; i++)
    {
        curr = new Node(data[i], n);
        currParent.children[currChildCount] = curr;
        parents.Enqueue(curr);

        currChildCount++;
        if(currChildCount >= n) // finished with children of this node, so start adding to children of the next.
        {                       // next node is either a sibling or a child but that is taken care of by Queue.
            currParent = parents.Dequeue();
            currChildCount = 0;
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this algorithm does not give me the right order of the nodes. see this picture: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5f6ae9f  Is there a way to reorder the tree in the correct form that I want? Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot construct the tree just from the given array. The reason is this. In your example, tree represents a pre-order traversal of the array. So the question is asking to construct a tree, given a pre-order traversal, which is not possible (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-you-are-given-two-traversal-sequences-can-you-construct-the-binary-tree/). We need more constraints, like an in-order traversal, in addition to given pre-order traversal.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found my solution. I edited the question and added the solution!

Comment: That's interesting. However, you can have different trees which can be constructed from the given pre-order traversal. May be the constraint here is that the tree needs to be complete which is achieved by the line `(int)ceil( log((double)n*(k-1) + 1 )/log((double)k))` in the solution you posted. Even with the constraint of completeness, I'm not sure whether one can construct a unique tree. But it looks like one can.

Comment: Okay, it turns out there is a unique COMPLETE k-ary tree for a given pre-order traversal. Which means the solution you posted will work.